# Symfony 2 Array an Input form

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any way to use something like this:

```
 ->add('dropdown',
            'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'ZabuluAvatarBundle:AddCategory',
                'data_class' => 'Zabulu\AvatarBundle\Entity\AddCategory',
                'required' => True,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $em) {
                    return $em->createQueryBuilder('c');
                },
                'property' => 'input',
                ))
            ;
```

but in an input text form?

My goal for this is to have an input type form that displays what is in the database, i.e. I have an entry from the database called "Cars", what would be displayed in the page would be an editable textbox with the word "Cars" in it. So for every entry in the database, there would be a textbox for it.

Comment: You probably want `CollectionType` http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: is the collectionType in the documentation for 2.7 same as the previous versions? I use 2.3 and I would like to know if 2.7 documentation is related. @dragoste

Comment: Here's doc for your version: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: Thanks! where the heck did you find this? I thought it was gone @dragoste

Comment: Just took URL for any other version and modified it manually. :D

Comment: I'm kind of confused with the documentation about the collection type, (this may seem kind of stupid but i'm not that symfony savvy) it doesn't seem to say how do I use something similar the the data_class for collectionType, or if I need some kind of relationship like one to many/many to many. @dragoste

Comment: There's `type` option which defines what `FormType` you use as a collection element. Doctrine's relations in your entities are out of scope of Form Component. But there's a note where to go for more information. You didn't read it carefully, did you? ;-) *If you are working with a collection of Doctrine entities,(...) see a complete example in the cookbook article How to Embed a Collection of Forms.* http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: It's true, I didn't read it as carefully as I should have cuz I tried to jump places in the documentation since I'm kind of rushing this project. I've read up to the "adding and removing items". @dragoste